# changing text inside label element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a code snippet:

```
<fieldset class="shareMe"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="share_me" name="share_me" value="1" {if $default_share_pref}checked="checked"{/if} onclick="if (this.checked) { var perms = 'publish_stream'; fb_login_cached(function(response){ if (!response.perms.match(new RegExp(perms))) $('share_me').checked = false; }, perms); }"/>
   <label for="share_me">Post this question to my friends on 
      <span class="">
         <a class="fb_button fb_button_small">
            <span class="fb_button_text">Facebook</span>
         </a>
      </span>.
   </label>
</fieldset>
```

I want to change the text in `<label for .. >` field via CSS.

I know i can do it by placing duplicate copy of this snippet and use css to toggle. However, i want to do it minimum code change. May be using some CSS trick to change `<label for..>` text and not affecting the code inside `<label for...>` at all.

Comment: CSS is for styles HTML is for markup. Don't even try to do one with the other.

Comment: Without being able to change the html, this would normally be done with JavaScript, not CSS. Is there a particular reason why you can't use JS?

Comment: Yes, i am not using JS, because the content is getting changed based on CSS3 media queries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't change text with CSS. The exception to this rule is the `::before` and `::after` psuedo-elements. In theory you could use classes to toggle the text like so:

```
label[for="share_me"]:before{content:'Post this question to my friends on '}
label[for="share_me"].othertext:before{content:'Some other text!'}
```

However, just because you can doesn't mean you should. It's an accessibility nightmare, and can you imagine coming back later and trying to work out where the text is coming from if not from the HTML?

Comment: can you update the snippet with exact place of implementation

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I strongly discourage the use of this code. Since you're probably using JavaScript to toggle classes, just use it to change the text.

Comment: no i am toggling classes using CSS by using block, overflow:hidden etc

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: may be that[using `content` property] is defamed as ugly solution but I see that it does lead to beautiful looking solutions..code gets simpler & easier to maintain

Comment: @user01 I agree, when used correctly. For instance, `div.dropzone:empty::before {content:'Drag something here!';}` would be an example of good usage.

Comment: what's really bad about the example that you listed in your answer ? Really I see no fault when it makes the code simpler other than the only fact it wont work with IE<8 ..

Answer (score 6):

Following the example at https://blog.escapecreative.com/how-to-replace-text-with-css/, this is what worked for me:

```
label[for="donate-choice-14724"]{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
label[for="donate-choice-14724"]:after{
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content:'Make this donation monthly';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [only change the content](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) of :before and :after pseudoelements with CSS. Ali Bassam's answer below shows a 'hacky' way to display the pseudoelements content over the parent so that you can control it. Problems with this solution include, well, how hacky it seems and also [the limited IE support](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) of pseudo elements. But that might not be problematic for your project.

Another thing to consider is that you'd have limited control over the toggle with CSS. Your two options are [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and the familiar [pseudo classes](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/). If your toggling needs go beyond what those guys can do, you'd do best [turning to Javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186041/change-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: i know JS was option. But did not want to use that.